# BCOR not part of paper dimensions

Tags: margins, koma-script, typearea

First of all: This is my first attempt using to the KOMA-classes.

It seems to me that the binding correction is not taken into account in what I am trying right now. If I understand `typearea` right, the following example should have a very tight outer margin.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrreprt}

\KOMAoptions{BCOR=5cm,paper=18cm:19cm,pagesize}
\areaset{12cm}{16cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\recalctypearea

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

However, this looks exactly the same as when I remove the `BCOR`.

How do I get my PDF to be the size of the paper on which the text should be printed (so with BCOR included)? I don't mind that on-screen the inner margins will look out of proportion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works if you apply the `BCOR` option *after*  `\areaset`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrreprt}

\areaset{12cm}{16cm}
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=5cm,paper=18cm:19cm,pagesize}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\recalctypearea

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`\areaset` has an optional argument to handle `BCOR`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,
  paper=18cm:19cm,pagesize
  ]{scrreprt}

\areaset[5cm]{12cm}{16cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

If `BCOR` is already set you can use the symbolic value `current`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,
  BCOR=5cm,paper=18cm:19cm,pagesize
  ]{scrreprt}

\areaset[current]{12cm}{16cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```