# BCOR not used inside scrreprt

Tags: koma-script

I am trying to set the BCOR for my bachelor thesis. My preamble looks like this

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,a4paper,oneside, 
listof=totoc,                   % Tabellen- und Abbildungsverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
bibliography=totoc,             % Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
titlepage,                      % Titlepage-Umgebung statt \maketitle
headsepline,                    % horizontale Linie unter Kolumnentitel
%abstracton,                    % Überschrift beim Abstract einschalten, Abstract muss dazu in {abstract}-Umgebung stehen
DIV12,                          % auskommentieren, um den Seitenspiegel zu vergrößern
BCOR=6mm,                       % Bindekorrektur, die den Seitenspiegel um 6mm nach rechts verschiebt,
]{scrreprt}
```

but BCOR is not taken into the dimension of my paper. I read in the KOMA documentation that I don't need to explicitly call `typearea` like this question: [BCOR not part of paper dimensions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60092/bcor-not-part-of-paper-dimensions)

I am also using `geometry` to change the default values for left, right, up and down size of my onesided paper.

```
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

As I have a onesided paper is it enough to just add 0.6 to my left value, making it 3,1cm?

Comment: You are using geometry, use its implementation as it has taken over. `bindingoffset=6mm`.

Answer (score 2):

The package `typearea` is loaded by `scrreprt` and sets the page layout.

```
\documentclass[
... 
headsepline,                    % horizontale Linie unter Kolumnentitel
...
BCOR=6mm,                       % Bindekorrektur, die den Seitenspiegel um 6mm nach rechts verschiebt,
]{scrreprt}
```

`BCOR=6mm` is the binding offset and the option `headsepline` sets automatically the option `headinclude=true`. Hence the page header belongs to the text during the layout calculation.

```
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

Now the package `geometry` redefines the page layout with its defaults, among others bindingoffset=0pt and headinclude=false that means headers belong to the top margin. And it changes of course the margins to the values given as arguments to `geometry`.

Note if you later use `\recalctyperea` or change one of the KOMA-Script options `DIV`, `BCOR`, `twoside` or `twocolumn` using `\KOMAoption` or `\KOMAoptions` the package `typearea` changes the pagelayout again.

So use

```
\usepackage[
  bindingoffset=6mm,
  %includehead,% if headers should belong to the text 
  left=2.5cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm
]{geometry}
```

to set the margins, the binding offset and maybe the option `includehead` and take care that `typearea` not recalculates the page layout.

Comment: *Only* as information: There is an unofficial and undocumented option `usegeometry` in the current KOMA-Script version 3.17a - see the [KOMA-Script website](http://www.komascript.de/releasesvn) (German). With `\documentclass[...,usegeometry]{scrreprt}[2015/05/06]` the package `geometry` only changes the values given in its argument or set by `\geometry{...}`.